# How to create pie wedge (sector) in PostGis by coordinates and azimuth?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I couldn't find correct answer and try to create function in PostGis which returned me polygon with geometry type.
This function can be use for visualize cellular network topology on map.
Below you can find this function for PostGis which is have next input parameters: lon , lat , azimuth , distance , width.
distance - length of pie;
width - width of pie.

```
create or replace function sector_3(lon float, lat float, azimuth float, distance integer, width integer)
returns geometry
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   sector geometry;
begin
    sector = ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326),
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth-(width/2))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth-(width/2-1*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth-(width/2-2*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth-(width/2-3*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth-(width/2-4*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth)/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth+(width/2-4*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth+(width/2-3*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth+(width/2-2*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth+(width/2-1*(width/2/5)))/180.0)::geometry,
                ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, pi()*(azimuth+(width/2))/180.0)::geometry,                                   
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)  
                     ]));
   return sector;
end;
$$;
```

As a result you will see sector which starts from given point (lon, lat) and with given distance(length) and width.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify things a bit by first creating a buffer from the parameters `distance`, `lon` and `lat` using [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html), so that you already have the are you want covered. The second step would be to cut out the piece of the buffer you want, and you can do that using [`ST_Split`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html). The function `ST_Split` expects a geometry and a blade to cut the geometry, and this blade can be created as a LineString based on the center point of the buffer (the reference coordinate pair), the `azimuth` and the `distance`, using [`ST_Project`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html). At this point you have two geometries - the area you want and the rest of the buffer - so you can use [`ST_GeometryN`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html) to only return the area that interests you:

```
WITH j (geom,azimuth,distance,width) AS (
  VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(38.94,45.05),4326),90,120,40)
)
SELECT  
  ST_GeometryN(
    ST_Split(
      ST_Buffer(geom::geography,distance)::geometry,
      ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[
        ST_Project(geom,distance+1,radians(azimuth-(width/2)))::geometry, geom,
        ST_Project(geom,distance+1,radians(azimuth+(width/2)))::geometry]
      )
   ),2)
FROM j;
```

[image]

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=79132dbc92cdeb818c7f8554880c7002)

To better illustrate the proposed solution the next query will depict the buffer, the projected points and the blade created based on them in three different CTEs.

```
WITH 
  original_values (geom,azimuth,distance,width) AS (
    VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(38.94,45.05),4326),90,120,40)), 
  points (array_points) AS (
    SELECT ARRAY[
      ST_Project(geom,distance+1,radians(azimuth-(width/2)))::geometry, geom,
      ST_Project(geom,distance+1,radians(azimuth+(width/2)))::geometry] 
    FROM original_values),
  line (blade) AS (
    SELECT ST_MakeLine(array_points) 
    FROM points),
  area (buffer) AS (
    SELECT ST_Buffer(geom::geography,distance) 
    FROM original_values   
  ) 
SELECT buffer FROM area
UNION
SELECT unnest(array_points) FROM points 
UNION 
SELECT blade FROM line;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this simplification, now it looks much better.

Comment: You can get into trouble with this depending on the units for distance and wedge angle. If you change the wedge line length to (distance * 2) instead of (distance + 1) it should handle any angle up to 120 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function sector_make(lon float, lat float, azimuth float, distance integer, width integer)
returns geometry
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   sector geometry;
   i integer;
 begin
  sector =  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);  
    for i in  (select 0-width/2)..(select width/2) 
    loop
        sector=ST_UNION(sector,ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, distance, radians(azimuth+i))::geometry);
    end loop;    
 return ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[sector,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)]));
end;
$$;
```